# ROCm 2019 Mac Book Pro

Tags: ubuntu, amd-rocm

I recently installed Ubuntu on my 2019 Macbook pro and installed ROCm successfully but am getting errors. Has anyone ran into this issue or does anyone know of any guides to help alleviate some of my stressors? lol....looking at some forums i see that it may be due to the kernel build. Also, im running an unsupported kernel due to the t2 chip in the MBPro... any options?

root@kyle-MacBookPro:/home/kyle# sudo /opt/rocm-4.5.0/bin/rocminfo
ROCk module is loaded
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: Cannot allocate memory
kyle is member of render group

Comment: Can you share details on your MBP model and the instructions, if any, that you followed. Did you use dual-boot or solo-boot? fwiw, I am trying to to this and fail when installing Grub.

Comment: i bailed and built a linux desktop but check out https://t2linux.org/...they have lots of good docs